# cannot align the header icon with body text in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am facing a very frustrating problem with bootstrap. I have a header and body with some headlines and texts. I have two icons in the header on the sides and I have couple of stories with some heading such as business in my example. I want my heading( business) to be left aligned with the icon at the right side. So "Business" should start exactly where my right icon in the header start and I would like to achieve this via bootstrap to remain the responsiveness capabilities. The following is the jsfiddle example of my code:

[jsfiddle](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB2528QGU0YC)

and here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">   </script>
<style>
  .grey-rule {
    padding: 0px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f0f3f7;
    }

  .grey-rule hr {
     display: block;
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     border-top: 10px solid #E5E8EC;
     }

 .story-label {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: #7F8DA2;
  padding: 8px 0px 12px 0px;
  } 

 .header {
    font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 30px;
     background-color: #4070CB;
     color: #EFF0F2;
     padding: 15px 0;
  }

 .center {
    text-align: center;
  }

 .txt {
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   text-align: center;
   justify-content: center;
  }

 .color1 {
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .color2 {
     background-color: orange;
   }

  .rightImg {
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 12px;
  }

 .leftImg {
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }

  .header a {
     color: white;
     font-size: larger;
   }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<div id="mainContainer" class="container-fluid">
    <div data-reactroot="">
        <div class="container-fluid col-sm-offset-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 center">
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div
                            class="col-lg-10 col-md-8  col-sm-8  hidden-xs  visible-sm visible-md visible-lg txt">TEST</div>
                        <div
                            class="col-lg-10 col-md-8  col-sm-8 col-xs-8 visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg txt"></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-1 center">
                            <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3 color1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 grey-rule">
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 story-label">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-2 center">Business</div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-8  col-sm-8 col-xs-8 txt"></div>
                                        <div
                                            class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-8 col-lg-1 center">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-4 col-lg-4 color2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 grey-rule">
                                    <hr>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 story-label">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-2 center">Business</div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-8  col-sm-8 col-xs-8 txt"></div>
                                        <div
                                            class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-xs-8 col-lg-1 center">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-3 col-lg-3 color1">.col-sm-4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can any one help? Am I doing it in the right way?

*************UPDATE**********************************

Just for sake of responsiveness, I do not wanna use margin-left and I want the header icon and the text to be aligned in all screen size

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the bootstrap classes right. Use one .col class per element. Ex. .col-sm-3 styles will break at 768px where .col-med-3 will break at 992px etc.

Below, I cleaned up your markup just to give you an idea how to do it.

This is the screenshot of the result: http://screencast.com/t/yb7UvAaSs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.grey-rule {
    padding: 0px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f0f3f7;
}

.grey-rule hr {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border-top: 10px solid #E5E8EC;
}

.story-label {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #7F8DA2;
    padding: 8px 0px 12px 0px;
}

.header {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: #4070CB;
    color: #EFF0F2;
    padding: 15px 0;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

.txt {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.color1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.color2 {
    background-color: orange;
}

.rightImg {
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.leftImg {
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.header a {
    color: white;
    font-size: larger;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="mainContainer" class="container-fluid">

        <div data-reactroot="">

            <div class="container-fluid col-sm-offset-1">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-sm-2">

                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></a>

                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-8  hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg txt">TEST</div>

                            <div class="col-sm-2">

                                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span></a>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm-10 color1">

                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-sm-12">

                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 grey-rule">

                                        <hr>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                        <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                                            <div>Test</div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-8">

                                            <div>Test</div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                                            <div>Business</div>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but what if I want to increase the size of a column in medium screen and decrease it in small screen then I need to use more than one .col class per element am I right?

Comment: Also this did not fix the issue of alignment

Comment: Try adding the .col-md and .col-lg to one of the .col-sm divs and resize your screen. You will notice that it will do the same thing as if you had col-sm only. I don't understand what you mean about issue of alignment. You asked if you are using bootstrap right and to left align the icon on the right and the business title below. That was achieved in the example above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By alignment I mean having business exactly below the first icon both align to the left

Comment: So what my jsfiddle show is correct I just want business to be vertically aligned by 3 line icon